# Big-O proof for a recurrence relation?

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

This question is fairly specific in the manner of steps taken to solve the problem.

Given 
$T(n)=2T(2n/3)+O(n)$ prove that $T(n)=O(n^2)$.

So the steps were as follows. We want to prove that $T(n) \le cn^2$.

$$\begin{align*}
T(n)&=2T(2n/3)+O(n)  \\
&\leq 2c(2n/3)^2+an\\
&\leq (8/9)(cn^2)+an
\end{align*}$$
and then my prof went on to do:

$$T(n) \leq cn^2+(an-(1/9)cn^2)\,,$$
which comes out to:

$$T(n)\leq cn^2 \text{ for any }c >= 9a\,.$$

My question is, how were they able to switch from 8/9 to 1/9 while introducing a new term? Is this allowed? She never explained, this was just in her solutions.

Comment: I don't see a new term introduced? We have that $cn^2 +an - (1/9)cn^2$ simplifies to $(8/9)cn^2 + an$ as in the line before. So the two lines are actually equal. Perhaps you're asking why one might want to do this?

Comment: I am also assuming the final line should read $cn^2$ as opposed to $ck^2$.

Comment: @ZacharyFrenette Ah you're right. in that case, i wasnt sure how she did the simplification. Why would one choose to separate the terms in that way? there are many ways to split (8/9). I think know why one would want to do this, to cancel out that extra $ an $? Otherwise the inequality won't hold. Also thanks for pointing out the typo, will fix. if you'd like to comment as an answer, i can accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you pointed out, the reason for splitting the term into two pieces is to be able to cancel the $an$ term. If we go directly from $(8/9)cn^2 + an \leq cn^2 + an$, then we get stuck as we cannot do anything with the $an$ term. By splitting it in the way described, this allows the $(1/9)cn^2$ to be larger than $an$ when $c \geq 9a$, which then gives you the desired result since $an - (1/9)cn^2 \leq 0$ for such values of $c$.